# Typescript initialize optional param in class

Tags: typescript

I have a class in typescript with several params, which are empty in the constructor.
I would like to have a default value for one of the optional params:

```
export class SomeClass {

    pageSize: number = 10;

    constructor(pagesize?: number){
        this.pageSize = pageSize;
    }
}
```

If I instantiate the class like this:

```
let k = new SomeTest()
```

The `pageSize` is `undefined`

How could I initialize a optional property?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the default value in the constructor:

```
export class SomeClass {

    pageSize: number;

    constructor(pagesize: number = 10){
        this.pageSize = pageSize;
    }
}
```

You can also define the property in the constructor:

```
export class SomeClass {
    constructor(public pagesize = 10){
    }
}
```